# How to watch a ruby class for method calls? (e.g. dependency injection, hooks, callbacks)

Tags: ruby

I have a Populater class for populating a database with random data. I would like to measure the populator's run method with the [rtui](http://github.com/nofxx/rtui/tree/master) progress bar. But instead of calling the progress bar object inside the Populater class, I would like to have a third class to increment the progress bar when certain methods in the Populater class are called. The code I have in mind is like this:

```
@populator = Populator.new
@pb = ProgressBar.new
Watcher.watch(@populator, :before, :add_record) do
  @pb.subject = "Adding a record..."
  @pb.inc
end
```

Watcher would call the watch block before executing @populator.add_record.

What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you look at the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). I'd avoid fancy dynamic tricks before they are really necessary, the observer pattern is simple and pretty well understood.

Also checkout the [Observable class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/observer/rdoc/index.html) in ruby's stdlib.

Comment: You are looking for something generic *mmm*.  you probably already know the observer pattern :). But yeah..

Comment: Yep. "Observe" is the word I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [RCapture](http://code.google.com/p/rcapture/), a Ruby library that allows placing hooks on methods using a simple and consistent interface.

Christoph

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it just work to do this:

```
def watch(populator, when, dowhat)
    yield
    populator.add_record
end
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I think the OP will change the target class/object dynamically.